# Факториал вещественных чисел

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Столкнулся с проблемой подсчета факториала, для натуральных чисел это сделать просто, но что делать, если нужно оперировать вещественными числами? Как считает стандартный калькулятор?
Пробовал использовать стандартную функцию tgamma, но она показывает не тот результат, что показывает стандартный калькулятор, поделитесь знаниями

Comment: при чем тут ios?

Comment: Использовал стандартную функцию tgamma, не знаю, есть ли она в других языках. Да, согласен, тег ios неуместен

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Возможно вы забыли прибавить единичку к аргументу? Не забывайте, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

откуда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверим:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {
  std::cout << "3! == Г(4) == " << tgamma(4.0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Г(4.5) == " << tgamma(4.5) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "4! = Г(5) == " << tgamma(5.0) << std::endl;
}
```

---

```
3! == Г(4) == 6
Г(4.5) == 11.6317
4! = Г(5) == 24
```

Такое же значение для "факториала" от 3.5 дает стандартный iOS калькулятор:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё верно. [+1]